# how to resolve Reported Attack Page

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis

when i opened my website and really got shocked. Because i'm getting "Reported Attack Page!" instead of my website.

I have studied a lot about this. I  have downloaded my whole website and i have inspected every page of website. There isn't any malicious code script. I have checked all Script files, CSS files and aspx pages.

I'm getting the exactly below window. I need someone's help to resolve this issue.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=163633

Answer (score 0):

Firefox uses Google Safe Browisng to find malicious websites. This page indicates that your website has been flagged by google as malware / phish . Resolve this issue with google webmaster : http://www.google.com/webmasters/

Some times it might be the case of ads that you are serving might contain malware , in that case you might have to talk to the ad provider.